# Program seems to be ignoring lines of code

Tags: android, logging, arraylist, logcat

I need help with this function.

I know that the if statement recognizes my input because it affects the program elsewhere, but I'm not sure what's going on because this particular Log doesn't display anything even in adb logcat.

Other Log statements in the same class file that this function is from display just fine, and the value update does seem to be changing ("show all" blanks it for some reason but I can figure that out after I get the log to work.)

I am unsure how to search for this problem because it is very specific and I have no idea what causes it (probably something simple that I didn't think of, though.)

```
void command(String input)
{

    //do stuff here
    //update = whatever
    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("show all"))
    {
        update=printAllRooms();
        Log.i(input, update);
    }
    else update=input; //just for testing, will delete later
}
```

the printAllRooms function:

```
public String printAllRooms() //for debug purposes
{
    String result = "";

    for (Iterator<Room> iterator = rooms.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Room current = iterator.next();
        result = result + current.toString()+"\n";
        Log.i("printallrooms", current.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: printAllRooms() returns a string?

Comment: Do you mean these lines are not executed? Please post your printAllRooms function.

Comment: add this `Log.i("TAG", input);` before your if statement.

Comment: log statement shows that the input is what I typed ("show all")

Comment: printAllRooms is a string.  Lines in that function appear to be not executed as well.  The string "update" is in a different scope so that any function in this object can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

A note on using Log.

The first argument sent to Log is typically a fixed string indicating the name of the class you are in.

So at the top of your class you might define:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyClassName";
```

Then you would use TAG for your log statements in that class.

```
Log.i(TAG, "My input was: " + input + " Update was: " + update;
```

To put it mildly, your function looks quite odd.  Set a breakpoint at your Log statement, run the debugger and then inspect the variable value contained in update.  Most likely, printAllRooms() is not doing what you think.

Comment: the best I've managed to narrow it down to so far is that the iterator in printAllRooms isn't returning any data even though the arraylist it gets it from is confirmed to be size 2

Answer (score 0):

If the iterator doesn't work for you, try using the For-Each loop:

```
for (Room r : rooms) {
    result = result + r.toString()+"\n";
    Log.i("printallrooms", r.toString());
}
```